# Video zooms in when embedding in Html5 using video tag

Tags: html, css, html5-video, blazor

I am embedding a video using html5 video tag. The video looks great on video player but whenever I embed it, it zooms in. How can I make sure it does not zooms in and fits the screen of web

Here is my Html

```
   <div class="video-wrapper">
            <div class="full-screen-video-component">        
                    <video style="height:100%;" loop="" muted="" autoplay="">
                        <source src="videos/Test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>           
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.full-screen-video-component {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}

video {
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
video {
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-30%) translateY(-30%) translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-30%) translateY(-30%) translateZ(0);
    transform: translateX(-30%) translateY(-30%) translateZ(0);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto !important
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I would like the video to not zoom in and stay the way it is when being embedded in the web. I am using simple Html5 in Blazor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes that can happen if you have a large-sized video. Try embedding the compressed version of the video. After that, you can remove the css to transform x and y axis and it should exactly embed like the video you have,